# Resetting the Azure Development Storage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, azure-compute-emulator

In Azure Development Storage's UI, there's a Reset button which stops, wipes, and restarts the devstore. Is there a programmatic way of doing this, similar to how I can stop and start the storage using

```
DevStore.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I haven't reset the devstore programmatically, I suppose you could shell out to DSInit.exe programmatically:

```
DSInit /ForceCreate
```

Comment: Not what I was hoping for, but at the very least it'll work in a pinch until someone else comes up with something. :-p

Answer (score 2):

@david-makogon's response is correct for the version of the SDK used in 2011, however in later versions of Azure Storage Emulator `dsinit` had been replaced with `WAStorageEmulator` and then with `AzureStorageEmulator`. (Maybe there was something else in between, but it doesn't matter as long as you use the latest SDK at the time of writing of this answer.)

A good overview of what's used at the moment can be found in [Use the Azure Storage Emulator for Development and Testing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-use-emulator/).

And regarding your question that would be:

1. Start `Azure Storage Emulator` to bring up the storage emulator command-line tool.
2. Run `AzureStorageEmulator init /forceCreate`